# "Column count doesn't match value count at row" but it does

Tags: mysql, count

I've got a mysql file with over than 14000 statements.
All of them are inserts into a table, and when I import the file using console, it throws the following error:

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01) at line 1548: Column count doesn't match value count at row 45
```

I know that error appears when the rows specified in column names are different from the rows specified in VALUES list, but I've checked it out many times and the number of columns is exactly the same in both lists.

The row in position 45 is:

```
('00553', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'XXXXXXXXR', 'user address', 'spain', 'spain', '39212', '1900-01-21', '123456789', 'M', 'No disponible', 0, 'AAA', 'BBB ', 'CCC', 'XXXXXXXXR', NULL, '888993344', '', '', '', '', 'no', 'no') --> 26 columns
```

and the insert line associated with it, many lines above is:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id_patient`, `name`, `surname1`, `surname2`, `dni`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `postal_code`, `birthday`, `telephone`, `sex`, `email`, `lopd_status`, `lopd_name`, `lopd_surname1`, `lopd_surname2`, `lopd_dni`, `lopd_as`, `mobile_phone`, `notes`, `job`, `company`, `place`, `active_citation`, `signature`)  --> 26 columns
```

I've looked for this error but it seems it only appears when count is different, but in this case, it is the same.

Any idea?

EDIT: forgot to mention: if I throw the sql statement directly on phpmyadmin, it adds the line correctly without any errors. It only crashes when run from command line, although the statements above it are correctly inserted into database and they are almost the same than this one.

EDIT2: I've removed all lines until the 46 and when I launch the file the erros is the following:

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01) at line 1503: Column count doesn't match value count at row 45
```

It only changes the line, but that line is the INSERT statement, which is exactly the same as the other INSERT statements in the rest of the file. The previos line is also correct.

Comment: check lines 44 and 46 as well...

Comment: I've also checked them and they also have 26 columns.

Comment: How does the create table statement for look for this table?

Comment: Try extracting the statement into a separate file and feed that to mysql. This should be easier to debug than 14000 statements at once.

Comment: It seems I've got a limitation in characters so I cannot put the full create table statement, but it has 30 fields, 4 of them are not inserted in the insert statement. The only values that cannot be null are the first 8, but in that line, all of them have a specified value, so the error cannot be about the values :S

I have also extracted the statement into a separate file so it only has the insert line and the values line, and throwing that statement directly into mysql has inserted it correctly into database.

Comment: It sounds like you have a limitation of 44.5 lines of data in whatever tool you are using.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I faced a similar problem because of inserting parenthesis around data :-(:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (Name,LastCredit,CreditDate) VALUES ( <-- Here.
    ("Nuclear Millitary Systems",500.0,CURRENT_DATE),
    ("Evil Corporation",67890.95,"2012-02-12"),
    ("Nuke Software Systems",5600.0,"2013-05-06"),
    ("RR Millitary",600.0,"2013-05-06"),
    ("Random Automation",560.0,"2012-05-01"),
    ("Evil Data Systems",600.0,"2013-03-01")
  );
```

Answer (score 23):

I was facing a similar error. It was just the matter of a missing comma. Check if all the items in the insert statement are separated by commas

Comment: This was just it! YACPG - Yet Another Copy-Paste Goofup :)

Answer (score 10):

In my case, my database table has a trigger associated to another table, and there was one column missing in triggered table. Something like this:

**Table1 columns:** UserAccountID, Document type, permissions, Status

**Triggered Table 2 columns:** Revision number, Revision Status, UserAccountID, Permissions, Status

So in the table 2, "document type" column was missing. 
Check the triggers in the DB by

"show triggers from {Database Name}"

Comment: That was my issue :)

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had a *trigger* on INSERT with column mismatch count **:(&**

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue too. @valplo's answer is right. Since I don't have enough reputation to comment, I write it here.

The correct way to insert multiple values is to list the values after the key word `VALUES`, not parenthesis around multiple value entries, but parenthesis around single value entries, and separate each single value entry with comma.

The wrong way is:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(column_name_0, column_name_1) VALUES(
    (val_00, val_01),
    (val_10, val_11)
);
```

The correct way is:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(column_name_0, column_name_1) VALUES
    (val_00, val_01),
    (val_10, val_11);
```

Comment: Maybe if you had more reputation, you wouldn't have posted an answer identical to the accepted answer from 6 years prior.

Answer (score 1):

Check for special hidden characters in the file. You might think that all whitespace in the file are spaces, but sometimes other characters can kill the insert in some way you can't understand by looking at the data.

If all else fails, retype the INSERT manually and run it in a file by itself to see if it still fails.

Comment: I have deleted all special characters in the line before and after that one but the error continues. I have also put that line and the next one into a separate file and mysql inserts them correctly into the database. This is starting to be frustrating...

Comment: Moreover, feeding mysql with a file containing the 4 lines before it and its following 4 lines also goes ok :(

Comment: I've imported the file into phpmyadmin but the error is the same.

Comment: Finally I decided to get rid of the entire file and export the table again, so after changing a few things, everything was imported.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the number of "?" in the prepared statement

```
prepare stmt1 from  "insert into company (name, address, phone) values(?,?);";
/*note only 2 question marks which should be 3.*/
```

This also will trigger the same error

```
insert into company (name, address, phone) values('foo','bar');
```