# #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 9

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1136

## 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 9.

can any one help me please ??

```
DELETE FROM Client;

INSERT INTO Client
(clientNo, fname, lname, sex, address, telNo, boatType, maxRent, email, staffNo) values

('CL001', 'Cole'    , 'Lamb'     , 'M', '457 Fermentum St, Balvano, P6 44R'   , 07824108257,   'Cruiser'  , '£80' , 'urna@fend.edu'     , 'ST006'),
('CL002', 'Tad'     , 'Schneider', 'M', '74 Rutrum Rd, Cropalati, WZ23 8BZ'   , '04290098211', 'Houseboat', '£140', 'ut@enim.com'       , 'ST022'),
('CL003', 'Orla'    , 'Ramsey'   , 'F', '8599 Vitae, Cerchio, D8C 6HL'        , '00459996970', 'Cruiser'  , '£80' , 'Nulla@aarcuSed.net', 'ST020'),
('CL004', 'Geoffrey', 'Miranda'  , 'M', '36 Arcu Rd, Recklinghausen, DN0K 9CV', '06122751320', 'Jet Boat' , '£66' , 'ante.Nunc@mi.ca'   , 'ST004'),
('CL005', 'Irene'   , 'Jacobson' , 'F', '56 Ut Road, avila, MV5 6SG'          , '04289108851', 'Jet Boat' , '£66' , 'tum@vel.ca'        , 'ST021'),
('CL006', 'Jaime'   , 'Frost'    , 'F', '52 Ut Road, avila, MV5 6AG'          , '07278866822', 'Jet Boat' , '£66' , 'Proin@idunt.ca'    , 'ST026');
```

Comment: you have mentioned 10 column names in your insert and 11 values in your values clause

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044901/column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-but-it-does

Comment: read the question again and you'll notice your very 1st value for TelNo is an INT value and then you are passing strings in rest of the records.

Answer (score 0):

If you type your query as below, it will be easier to count the number of fields and values.  It will also make it less likely to forget a comma.

```
insert into client (
field1
, field2
, etc
)

values

(value1
, value2
, etc
)

, (value1
, value2
, etc
)
etc
```